# AngularJS call callback function

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

I want to call a callback function but i can't get the data because my call is wrong.

I tried:

```
//function with callback
filterList: function(type, cb) {

 if (type == 'all') {
  var resource = infoboxApi.resource1().query();
 } else if (type == 'group') {
  var resource = infoboxApi.resource2().query();
 }

 resource.$promise.then(function(events) {
  var eventContainer = [];
  angular.forEach(events, function(event) {                  
   eventContainer.push({
    id: event.id,
    title: event.title
   })
  });
  cb(eventContainer);
 });

 return wrapSaveHandlers(resource);
 }



//call i tried
var newSources = [];
filterList('all', function(result) {
 newSources = result;
});
```

I want newSources to contain the data but it's empty if i call it like this.

Anyone know how to call it the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using callbacks in promise-based APIs. Instead use [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statements:

```
 //function without callback
 filterList: function(type) {
     var resource;       
     if (type == 'all') {
         resource = infoboxApi.resource1().query();
     } else if (type == 'group') {
         resource = infoboxApi.resource2().query();
     };

     //RETURN the promise
     return resource.$promise.then(function(events) {
         var eventContainer = [];
         angular.forEach(events, function(event) {                  
             eventContainer.push({
                 id: event.id,
                 title: event.title
             })
         });
         //RETURN the data
         return eventContainer;
     });
 }
```

And extract the data from the returned promise:

```
var newSources = [];
filterList('all').then(function(result) {
    newSources = result;
});
```

The `.then` method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the `successCallback`, `errorCallback` (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using [promise chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues).

Comment: ty for this code but if i look into newSources it's still empty after the call of filterList

Comment: Use standard debugging to techniques to determine where the data is being lost. Insert `console.log` statements. Review the network tab in the Developer Console.